# Help me understand this CSS overriding behavior

Tags: css

Why does `#box2 a` overrides `#box a` and when I put `.box2 a` it doesn't override?

```
#box a { font-size:25px; }
#box2 a { font-size:55px; }

<div id="box">
<a href="">link</a>
<div id="box2"><a href="">link</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: '.' refers to a class name, '#' refers to an id.

Comment: If you change the css to `.box2` and set the div to `class="box2"`, it will use 25px instead of 55px. That's what he is saying.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Answer (score 1):

CSS rules always occur in order of appearance, so if two apply to a specific element, the one appearing last would have precedence.

Also, as mentioned, if you use `.box2` that would apply to an element with the class name `box2`, whereas `#box2` would apply to an element with an id of `box2`

[**Understanding CSS Style Precedence**](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/)

[**Another Stack Overflow question relating to CSS classes and ids, and precedence**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667223/css-precedence)

Answer (score 0):

Because you may did not add a `class="box2"`. The `.` refers to classes. `#` is for id.

Comment: He is referring to swapping them within the context as well.