# a link not overrite by css

Tags: html, css

In my CSS I have a main container with id `main`. In the CSS it looks like this:

```
#main a:hover, #main a:active, #main a:focus {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #095197;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

In a particular `div` I want the link style to be different:

```
.main_list_div .text_div .mainbt a.bt {
    width: 100px;
    height: 26px;
    background: url(../image/bt.png) no-repeat;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 22px;
    text-decoration: none
}
.main_list_div .text_div .mainbt a.bt:hover,
.main_list_div .text_div div.mainbt link.bt:hover {
    width: 100px;
    height: 26px;
    background: url(../image/bth.png) no-repeat;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent
}
```

My HTML is:

```
<div class="main_list_div">         
    <div class="image_div"><img src="images/directory/1338033387.jpg"></div>
    <div class="text_div">
        <div class="company_name">Yahoo India</div> 
        <div class="category_name">Manufacturers of Primary Category / Secondary Category / Secondary Category</div> 
        <div class="mainbt"><a href="directory-list/yahoo/yahoo-india.html" class="bt"></a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is `a (link)` is overridden but `a:hover` is not. How do I override `a:hover` ?

Comment: where's .mainbt? try removing that one maybe that helps.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add class `mainbt`, see i have add in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the issue is that the first rule `#main a:hover` has higher precedence that the second rule `.main_list_div .text_div .mainbt a.bt:hover`. If I recall correctly id selectors have a weight of 100, class and attribute selectors a weight of 10 and element selectors a weight of 1, the rule with the highest precedence wins - if there are rules with the same precedence then the position that the rules are defined is used to determine the outcome. In your example the first rule would have a precedence of 111, the second 51.

As mentioned in other answers you don't have a `.mainbt` element.

Just found another SO answer that [explains precedence in more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/667585/540765).

Comment: it means to override any `#id` id makes div with id

Comment: @Toms: Yes. The simplest solution would be to add `#main` to the start of the second rule. This would remove the need to change any of your HTML.

Answer (score -1):

It seems there is no element with `mainbt` class anywhere. So the css selector won't match.

You should probably use selector like:

```
.main_list_div .text_div a.bt:hover { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote for no reason, hope you enjoyed :-) By the time I was writing this the question looked way different.