# switchClass failing after jQuery hover function on jQuery cycle element

Tags: jquery, background, hover, cycle

I have a page using the jQuery cycle plugin for a sliding banner, and inside each slide is a div (`#info`) whose background colour is animated on hover.

I'm also trying to use switchClass to switch between three color-schemes on the page and this also changes the background colour of `#info`, which works great until the hover on `#info` fires, after which the switchClass buttons no longer work.

Here's the jQuery for the hover:

```
$('#info.default').hover(function(){
        $('#info.default').stop().animate({backgroundColor: '#CDBF21'}, 300);
        $('#info.default .description').stop().animate({color: '#444'}, 300);
    }, function() {
        $('#info.default').stop().animate({backgroundColor: '#203E52'}, 300);
        $('#info.default .description').stop().animate({color: '#fff'}, 300);
    });
```

And here are the switchClass parts:

```
$('.coral-green-button').click(function(){
        $('#info.default').stop().switchClass("default", "coral-green", 1000 );
        $('#info.green-blue').stop().switchClass("green-blue", "coral-green", 1000 ); 
    });

$('.green-blue-button').click(function(){
        $('#info.coral-green').stop().switchClass("coral-green", "green-blue", 1000 );
        $('#info.default').stop().switchClass("default", "green-blue", 1000);
    });

$('.mustard-blue-button').click(function(){
        $('#info.coral-green').stop().switchClass("coral-green", "default", 1000);
        $('#info.green-blue').stop().switchClass("green-blue", "default", 1000);
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle.net replicating the issue you are having?

Comment: sure - I have it set up here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6zsm/6/

Comment: Where is it breaking?  Sorry I'm not understanding what isn't happening

Comment: OK - I've updated it a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6zsm/7/ - basically once the hover effect fires once, the switchClass no longer works

Comment: Oh ok.. That helps alot now.. I didn't know exactly what the problem was.. I'll see what if I can find anything

Comment: It has something to do with level of precedence.. As you can see in the console.  The hover is more specific as it's setting the background directly to a certain color.  So when you try to change the class - it changes but the css change in the hover is more specific - thus causing it to stay the colors of the hover.

Comment: Read this post.. It will help you understand how css specificity works http://stackoverflow.com/a/667585/1385672

Comment: Also your page has a BUNCH of dom elements that have the same ID.... which is BAD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this isn't perfect but it is a step in the correct direction:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutmatt/Q6zsm/19/

your element (on hover) is getting a new background that is a ELEMENT specific property therefor a class level background color CANNOT override that

Better:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutmatt/Q6zsm/24/

Best:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutmatt/Q6zsm/49/

Comments inline

Comment: Hey, thanks! This is really helpful. Could you explain your comment about having lots of DOM elements with the same ID? Does each slide in the cycle need a unique ID? Thanks!

Comment: Your IDS need to be unique but you can add a class and call the class in jquery with a .className.  I will modify the bottom jsfiddle for you with that comment...  Don't forget to mark the answer correct if it is.

Comment: On a note I didn't add a class to the info I just changed the selector to use an 'id starts with' selector