# css styles being ignored on second stylesheet

Tags: html, css, styles, stylesheet

Just a question no need for code adjustments!

So i have a main 'style.css' and inside that file i use the '@import url("custom.css");'

I have a style inside the  `top-container: margin-top:20px;` but the site won't display the change..

If i move the `top-container: margin-top:20px;` to the style.css it works fine..

If I add `top-container: margin-top:20px!important;` that also works..

I can't understand why it would style is being ignored .

Comment: Sounds like a specificity issue to me. Add the `import` to the bottom of the stylesheet.

Comment: I thought import had to be at the top... no?

Comment: My bad - you're right.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import I'd suggest looking into how specificity is calculated here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity It's likely that you could make the selector more specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS precedence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667223/css-precedence)

Comment: I think I figured it out.. in my code i had a row { margin 0 auto } and it was hiding on me... meanwhile I was calling the custom.css before this code which gave me the issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.. in my code i had a row { margin 0 auto } and it was hiding on me... meanwhile I was calling the custom.css before this code which gave me the issues. –