# Class overriding Main tag

Tags: html, css

I have the following code on line 69 of my css

`.container {width:1000px;margin:0 auto;padding:0 10px;}`

And the following on line 119

`main {margin:20px auto;}`

However the element in my html which is `<main class="container"></main>`, the margin on `.container` is overriding the margin on `main`, even though `main` is loaded after it in the css. Can anyone tell me why this is???

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS precedence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667223/css-precedence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Priority is most important in css. High Priority is  always gives for id selector
and then class selector and then priorty comes for elemnent or tag selector

```
Priority

1) # - id selector

2) . - class selector

3) <> - element or tag selector
```

In the example

```
<main class="container"></main>
```

main is a tag and container is a class contain in a main tag. From css class selector(container) take more priority than element selector(main). so it overides the property of main tag.

Answer (score 3):

Class selectors (like `.foo`) are more specific than type selectors (like `bar`). Specificity is used to determine the order in which rules are applied. Source code order is the tie break condition.

See [the specificity rules in the CSS 2.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) for more detail.

Comment: I was searching everywhere for that page. Thanks! :)