# Issues with default CSS taking over my code

Tags: css, css-selectors, navbar, css-specificity

I've been working on my donation website and I've come to find an issue where the default Buycraft css is taking over the css that I'm writing. I'm extremely new to css and I don't plan on doing it much in the future but for now I need help.

When I inspect element my navbar it gives me a few variables for `.navbar .nav > li > a` such as a color and a text shadow. I've tried to re-write the code for the text and it's to no avail. I copied it exactly like what inspect element has and I gave the variables !important but nothing changes. If anyone can tell me whats wrong with the navbar button text please help me out.

My [website](http://donate.casualsb.com).

**Code:**

```
@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300";

body {
  background:url(http://i.imgur.com/tYtIxao.jpg?1);
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  height:100%
}

.navbar {
  background:#11CFD9;
  position:fixed;
  font-family:"Oswald";
  top:0;
  left:-5px;
  right:-5px;
  background-color:#11CFD9;
  color:#000!important;
  box-shadow:0 2px 2px 0 rgba(50,50,50,0.24);
  text-align:center;
  height:80px;
  display:block;
  padding-left:5%;
  padding-right:20%;
  z-index:10
}

.navbar-inner {
  background:#11CFD9;
  position:fixed;
  font-family:"Oswald";
  top:0;
  left:-5px;
  right:-5px;
  background-color:#11CFD9;
  font-size:x-large;
  text-align:center;
  display:block;
  padding-top:30px;
  padding-bottom:30px;
  padding-left:5%;
  padding-right:20%;
  z-index:10
}

.navbar .nav>li>a {
  float:none;
  padding:10px 15px;
  color:#000!important;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-shadow:0 0 0 #fff!important
}

.nav > li > a {
  display:block;
  color:#000!important
}

a {
  color:#08c;
  text-decoration:none
}

.navbar .nav > .active > a,.navbar .nav > .active > a:hover {
  color:#fff;
  height:auto;
  text-decoration:none;
  background-color:#11CFD9;
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0;
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0
}

ul.nav a:hover {
  color:#fff!important;
  background:#1CDBE6
}

.box-container .basket-dropdown {
  padding:20px;
  margin-left:-145px;
  margin-top:2px
}

.basket-dropdown .checkout {
  float:right
}

.checkout {
  z-index:9999;
  font-family:Oswald;
  font-weight:300
}

.row {
  margin-left:20px;
  margin-right:20px
}

.box-container .checkout {
  width:98%!important;
  float:none!important
}

.span11 {
  width:98%;
  float:none!important
}

.box {
  background:url();
  border:0!important;
  margin-top:130px;
  position:relative;
  padding-right:25px;
  padding-left:25px;
  width:100%
}

.box-container {
  font-family:Oswald;
  font-weight:300;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-left:5px
}

.box-container .checkout {
  width:90%;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  z-index:0;
  top:0
}

.box-container .header {
  background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/PzVJZ4V.png);
  background-color:#fff;
  border-top-left-radius:1px;
  border-top-right-radius:1px;
  -webkit-border-radius-topright:5px;
  -webkit-border-radius-topleft:5px;
  -border-radius-topright:5px;
  -border-radius-topleft:5px;
  height:33px;
  text-align:left;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:25px;
  padding-top:20px;
  font-family:Oswald;
  font-weight:300;
  border-radius:5px 5px 0 0
}

.box-container .content {
  opacity:.9!important
}

.span7 {
  width:60%;
  margin-left:20px;
  border-radius:10px
}

.span4 {
  width:25%;
  height:15%
}

.clear-fix {
  z-index:9999;
  top:0;
  opacity:.9
}

.logo {
  background:url();
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  float:none;
  z-index:9999;
  position:fixed;
  left:25%;
  height:0!important;
  width:0!important
}

.logo span {
  opacity:0;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:0
}

em {
  color:red;
  font-weight:700;
  font-style:normal
}

/*Spinny Heads*/
.image {
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
  -webkit-transition:.5s all ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:.5s all ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:.5s all ease-in-out;
  transition:.5s all ease-in-out
}

.image:hover {
  -webkit-transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1.5);
  -moz-transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1.5);
  -o-transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1.5);
  transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1.5)
}

.footer {
  height:60px;
  border-top:1px solid #000;
  background:orange;
  bottom:0;
  margin-right:0;
  margin-bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  z-index:99999;
  position:static;
  font-family:"Oswald";
  left:-5px;
  right:-5px;
  background-color:#11CFD9;
  color:#000!important;
  box-shadow:0 2px 2px 0 rgba(50,50,50,0.24);
  text-align:center;
  display:block
}
```

Comment: Put a space before !important.

Comment: Avoid `!important` where ever possible. http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser decides which css selector is applied over the others depending on its *weight*. Usually you will find the term **CSS specificity** describing this.

In your case the `.nav > li > a` is interpreted to have a very low weight and is therefore overridden by your default stylesheet.
If you remove the `>` symbols in those selectors it should still be the same result - since there are no nested `a` elements in the navigation bar you want to exclude, right?

The selector `.nav li a` has a bigger weight and should therefore take precedence. If that still does not help, please include the css-selector from your Buycraft css file, which is overriding your selector. So we can look at the specific weight of both in comparison.

Have a look at [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/667585/5127499) for another example.

---

A little background: the css specificity exists in order to make things like the following possible: Imagine, the links on your website should always be displayed in blue. But in your navigation, they should be black.

```
a { color: blue; }
.navbar a { color: black; }
```

Since the second selector is more specific, it takes precedence over the general links-are-blue selector and your navigational links are black.

Comment: Thank you! Removing the >'s overrode the default Buycraft css and fixed the issue! Like I said I'm extremely new to css, I don't plan on doing it a ton but I do enjoy it. I also have one more issue that I need assistance with if you could help me out. When I make a button that is a dropdown, active, It seems to override the settings I have set for button hover. I assume its simply because its a dropdown and it works differently, but I've google the living hell out of it and I can't seem to find out how to make it so it highlights the dropdown button and doesnt override it with the default.

Comment: I'm afraid that comment alone is not enough for me to help. Please accept this answer and create a new question - or include the button issue in your question with more details of your css selectors and what the invalid button state looks like in the html.

Comment: Ahh sorry. I fixed the issue by just inspect element and found out what to change. I'm all set now. :D